# Happy birthday, Philosophy.SE!

Tags: discussion, community

Well, friends, it's been a whole year since we kicked off Philosophy.SE! I wanted to take a moment to reflect on our achievements and consider the road ahead. I'd love to hear about your favorite questions or answers from the past year, or any ideas you might have on interesting projects we might start putting together in our second year. Congratulations, everyone!

Answer (score 3):

My favorite question is my own:

- [Is Kurt Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem a “cheap trick”?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/210/73)

My second favorite is still an open one, I see:

- [Are the unexamined lives of others worth examining?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/138/73)

Whenever my reading swings around to philosophy, it's nice to know that Philosophy.SE is waiting in the wings to take my questions.  It's been a while since I've been an active member of the community, but I really appreciate the work y'all are doing to keep this site active.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to mention that there are now **180 questions and answers** on Philosophy.SE that earned a great question or answer badge (i.e., that have a minimum of 10 votes.)

[Please check them out here!](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search?q=votes:10&submit=search) I think it is pretty inspiring that the community has generated this much awesome content in less than a year. Great job, everyone.